# error of ploting 3D surface in python 3.2 by matplotlib win 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, matplotlib, 3d

I would like to make a 3D surfaceplot in python 3.2 by matplotlib on win 7.

I used the example at http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contourf3d_demo2.html

My code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

def plotFunc():
  x = np.linspace(0.00001,70 ,10)  # x is a list of numbers
  y = np.linspace(0.01, 70,10)
  result = np.linspace(0.01, 70,10)
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

  ax.plot_surface(x, y, result, rstride=5, cstride=5, alpha=0.3)
  ax.set_xlabel('shape')
  ax.set_xlim(0, 70)
  ax.set_ylabel('scale')
  ax.set_ylim(0, 70)
  ax.set_zlabel('result')
  ax.set_zlim(0, 70)

  plt.show()
```

But, I got nothing in the output except teh three axises when I call it.

**update**

After using matplotlib backend,

```
 import matplotlib
 matplotlib.use('PDF')

 ax.plot_surface(shape, scale, result, rstride=5, cstride=5, alpha=0.3)
 plt.savefig('test.pdf') # AttributeError: rint
```

I got the error:

```
 AttributeError: rint
```

at

```
 plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you never called the function.

Comment: also `//` is not a valid comment in python, so you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: @Paul H, I called it from another function. it gave me nothing. Thanks !

Comment: use `plt.savefig('test.png')` instead of `show`. if you get a file, you're probably just not using an interactive backend. See http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Comment: @Paul H, what if I want to see it on screen ? thanks !

Comment: then use an interactive backend. put `import matplotlib; matplotib.use(<mybackend>)` at the top of the script (per the link in my previous comment)